# Phantom of Eldberg Contract - Can you access the Lighthouse afterwards?

Tags: pc, the-witcher-3

The Witcher Contract, Phantom of Eldberg, has 2 possible outcomes:

- One where you talk to Mikkjal directly after examining the signs on the outside of the lighthouse
- One where you continue investigating the lighthouse, and discover "dark secrets" (and then talk to Mikkjal)

Is there a way to get in the lighthouse after the quest was finished, if you didn't continue investigating?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just go into the lighthouse after the quest is completed. However, I suspect you won't be able to do anything with the letters, as they were a quest item.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to get into the lighthouse, it says it's locked, but to be honest the only difference getting these letters will make is Geralt telling Mikkjal that he knows the bad things he's done and telling Jorund that he should find a new lighthouse keeper.
It's just that I was not satisfied with the outcome xD

Comment: Ah - did you get the key from Mikkjal before looking around the lighthouse?

Comment: I believe so because after examining the signs, I went and tried to open the doors but maybe that's the reason I can't find the key now, maybe when I opened the lighthouse I used the key and it was gone and now I can't open the door, also, thanks for editing the question, you made it way cleaner and easier for the eye :D